# Build Java 6 Project with Maven 3.0 and Jenkins 2.1XX : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and I am currently setting up some automated builds on a local server we have. Half of the projects are using JDK 8 with Maven 3.3+ and works pretty fine. 
However, We have other older projects that we still need to build that requires JDK 6 and Maven 3.0 (it should work with Maven 3.2 too). Using Eclipse IDE, the project compile successfuly but when run by a Jenkins Maven job, it returns this error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jvnet/hudson/maven3/agent/Maven3Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

I checked that Jenkins uses the right JDK and Maven version which are mentionned in the trace :

> $ **/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/java** -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/usr/share/maven-3.0.5/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main **/usr/share/maven-3.0.5** /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3.17.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.12-alpha-1.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.12-alpha-1.jar 45589

I've read some thread about Jenkins no longer being able to build Java projects with JDK older than 8 (I've only searched about Maven though).
It makes sense looking at the console output, Jenkins looks like he tries to retrieve some of its own files using the job's specified JDK (6), but I don't really get why he needs to do so ? Is it related to Jenkins' Core ?

Upgrading the projects to Java 8 isn't an option, nor downgrading Jenkins.
Is there a workaround in order to build a Java 6 project with Jenkins using Maven ?

I've tried using `-Dmaven.compiler.source=1.6 -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.6` in the MAVEN_OPTS but doesn't work either.
There's probably something I missed as I'm new to Jenkins but couldn't find out after some hours. I'm not against a helping hand, thanks.

Here is the end of the console output :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jvnet/hudson/maven3/agent/Maven3Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Could not find the main class: org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.  Program will exit.
ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = 1
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: You can compile Java 6 projects with a Java 8 JVM.

Comment: Jenkins needs JDK 8 that looks like the problem you seemed to be trying to run Jenkins with JVM lower than JDK 8...You can't run a Maven Job Type in jenkins with a differerent JDK than Jenkins itself is running. If you have such requirement you have to use Freestyle job type...